# How to get Ajax Post Request Parameters in Java

Tags: javascript, java

I am Passing a list of Java Objects to Javascript function that sends an ajax post request with the same data:

```
<%List<PfsRequestBean> requestsList = (List<PfsRequestBean>) request.getAttribute("requestsList");%>
<button  onclick="exportExcel('<%=requestsList%>')"> Export </button>
```

Java Script Function:

```
function exportExcel( data )
{
    showLoader();
    debugger;
    
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/GeneralObservation.do?actionCommand=EXPORT_EXCEL',
      data: data,
      success: function() {
            alert( "exported successfully.." );
            hideLoader();
      }
    });
}
```

Java Action Class; How to get the posted list here ?

```
    else if( "EXPORT_EXCEL".equalsIgnoreCase(command) )
    {
        HttpServletRequest req = request;
        
        //how to get posted data here... ?
        
        setReturnPage( SEARCH );
    }
        
    return mapping.findForward( getReturnPage() );
```

Thank you for your response!

Comment: [nothing useful here](https://www.google.com/search?q=Ajax+Post+Request+Parameters+Java+site:stackoverflow.com) ?

Comment: Don't mix and match the different levels of execution. You cannot pass a Java list to a JavaScript function. The JSP is executed at server side and generates your HTML+JS response. The browser receives text generated by the server. Look at the browser's developer tools to check what is actualliy generated. When the browser executes the JavaScript there are no Java objects anymore. So you have to generate the HTML and JavaScript so that it makes sense for the browser.